# Generic detail view BookDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Tags: python-3.x, django

i am new in django. i work on a project .
it is my bookdetailview::

```
class BookDetailView(generic.DetailView):

    model = models.Book
    template_name = 'catalog/book_detail.html'
```

and this is my renewbooklibririan that define in views::

```
def renew_book_librarian(request, pk):
        """
        View function for renewing a specific BookInstance by librarian
        """
        book_inst=get_object_or_404(models.BookInstance, pk = pk)
    
        # If this is a POST request then process the Form data
        if request.method == 'POST':
    
            # Create a form instance and populate it with data from the request (binding):
            form = RenewBookForm(request.POST)
    
            # Check if the form is valid:
            if form.is_valid():
                # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required (here we just write it to the model due_back field)
                book_inst.due_back = form.cleaned_data['renewal_date']
                book_inst.save()
    
                # redirect to a new URL:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('catalog:my-borrowed') )
    
        # If this is a GET (or any other method) create the default form.
        else:
            proposed_renewal_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(weeks=3)
            form = RenewBookForm(initial={'renewal_date': proposed_renewal_date,})
    
        return render(request, 'catalog/book_renew_librarian.html', {'form': form, 'bookinst':book_inst})
```

and this is my url pattern:

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.Index.as_view(), name = "index"),
     path('books/', views.BookListView.as_view(), name = "books"),
     path('authors/', views.AuthorListView.as_view(), name = 'authors'),
     path('book/<int:book_id>/', views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name = "book-detail"),
     path('mybooks/', views.LoanedBooksByUserListView.as_view(), name = 'my-borrowed'),
     path('book/<int:book_id>/renew/', views.renew_book_librarian, name='renew-book-librarian' )

]
```

my code is working until add the renew-book-libririan in the urls.
when i add this url i have this error::
((Generic detail view BookDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.))

can anyone help me??!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a `DetailView` will look for a url parameter named `pk` or `slug` to obtain the item. But here you named the parameter `book_id`.

You can however specify in the [**`pk_url_kwarg`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg) the name of the url parameter:

```
class BookDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Book
    pk_url_kwarg = 'book_id'
    template_name = 'catalog/book_detail.html'
```

For your function-based view, the name of the parameter should be `book_id`:

```
def renew_book_librarian(request, book_id):
    book_inst=get_object_or_404(models.BookInstance, pk=book_id)
    # …
```